# [apache ignite]ignite cache data lost when i create the primary and backup cache

Tags: ignite

I run an example with two ignite cache node in two jvm. each jvm runs a ignite node. the nodes map to the same cache.

ignite-config.xml

```html
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    ...
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <!-- Set a cache name. -->
            <property name="name" value="cacheName"/>
            <!-- Set cache mode. -->
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
            <!-- Number of backup nodes. -->
            <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            ... 
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

test steps:

1. one of the ignite nodes start first and write 10 pieces of
   data(key-value: 1-1,2-2,3-3...10-10).
2. then the second one start and map to the cache.
3. then ignite nodes start to rebalancing data
   for them. the first node has 4 pieces, the second has 6 pieces.
4. then i kill the jvm of first cache node.

result: the backup node doesn't own 10 pieces as i expect.why?

Comment: This should not happen. How do you check which entries are owned by which nodes? Can you show the test code?

Comment: @Valentin i use the ignitevisorcmd.sh，it offer a cmd：cache -swap and cache -scan -c=@c0 -id8=@n0

Comment: Did you try querying the cache after you kill the one node?  Or did you just use the ignitevisorcmd.sh.  It could be a bug in the monitoring software as well so you should test if it has the keys after by querying.  (Not likely, but a possibility)  Does it make it difference which node you kill?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas maybe，i will test it tomorrow. do you test it before？can you give me an example it really works.

Comment: `cache -scan` shows only primary entries I think. What `IgniteCache.size()` returns after the node is killed?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas i works when query from the code

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas thank you！

Comment: @Valentin thanks，i got my answer.

Comment: Hey, what was the answer?  If it was something I said let me know and I can write it up for the pointssss

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas i use the cache.get() interface to check the value after I kill one node,then I  found all pieces of the data are existed, no data lost.

Comment: @Valentin Even if it only shows primary keys, shouldn't they become primary keys once the other node is killed?

Comment: They will, but probably not immediately. Unless there is a bug in Visor, of course :)

Comment: I tried something similar, I have 3 nodes, I use PARTITIONED with backups=3 and FULL_SYNC. I use TcpDiscoverySpi instead of TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder. I load 5million records with all 3 nodes. When I bring one node down and do the data count i get only 3.75 million records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `ignitevisorcmd.sh` is reporting the keys are lost.  I suggest looking directly into the cache by querying it after you kill the node.  Or as Valentin Suggests, you can try IgniteCache.size()